# Enable RSS feed for tags

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would be nice to get an RSS feed for an **specific tag**.

Tag pages showing lists of corresponding answers display an RSS button which always points to the "all answers" feed.

After checking the askbot site, their links to RSS feed in a tag page can generate this kind of tag feed via HTML param *"?tags="*. Probably is a question to update the whole askbot since theirs is in 0.7.32 and *answers.ros.org* 0.6.74.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12590/enable-rss-feed-for-tags/) by [jrivero](https://answers.ros.org/users/440/jrivero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-01-11**:
I concur that this would be useful, at least until email notifications work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We will be upgrading the version of askbot which answers.ros.org runs soon.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1